# Querying database through Hive/Thrift in PHP does not work

Tags: php, database, hadoop, hive, thrift

I'm trying to query a database through Hive/Thrift in PHP. However, I am constantly getting an error:

```
TSocket: timed out reading 4 bytes from XYZ
```

I'm using a code from

https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveclient.html#HiveClient-PHP

along with this PHP Thrift Client

https://github.com/garamon/php-thrift-hive-client

My code:

```
<?php

$socket    = new TSocket( 'XYZ', 12345 );

$socket->setSendTimeout(30 * 1000);
$socket->setRecvTimeout(30 * 1000);

$transport = new TBufferedTransport( $socket, 1024, 1024 );
$protocol  = new TBinaryProtocol( $transport );

$client    = new ThriftHiveClientEx( $protocol );

$transport->open();

$client->execute("my query");

?>
```

Note - I am able to connect with XYZ through console (telnet command).

I would appriciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when starting with those exact same resources.  It turns out the code is not recognizing whether it has timed out or whether it is blocking the port.  I found this article which helped me:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-347

In your TSocket.php code ( garamon_base_dir/lib/transport ) you have to edit approximately lines 223 through 236.

Where it says:

```
if( $buf === FALSE || $buf === '' ) { ...
and
if( $md['timed_out'] ) { ...
and then again
if( $md[timed_out'] ) { ...
```

change to (respectively):

```
if( $buf === FALSE ) { ...
and
if( true === $md['timed_out'] && false === $md['blocked'] )
and finally 
if( true === $md['timed_out'] && false === $md['blocked'] )
```

Then it started working after this fix.  Good luck!