# HiveServer2 TTransportException: Invalid status -128

Tags: javascript, node.js, hive, thrift, cloudera-cdh

I'm using a node.js client driver for hive called **jshs2**, but I came across a connection problem while connecting to our hiveserver2. I tried to look up invalid status 128, but had no luck. Here is my code:

```js
const options = {
 auth: "NOSASL",
 host: "my host",
 port: 10000,
 timeout: 10000,
 username: "my username",
        password: "my password"
 hiveType: HS2Util.HIVE_TYPE.CDH,
 hiveVer: "0.13.1",
 thriftVer: "0.9.0",
 cdhVer: "5.3.3"
};


it('test', function() {
 var configuration = new Configuration(options);
 var idl = new IDLContainer();
 var cursor;
 return idl.initialize(configuration).then(function() {
  var connection = new HiveConnection(configuration, idl);
  return connection.connect();
 }).then(function(_cursor) {
  cursor = _cursor;
  return cursor.execute(options.query);
 }).then(function() {
  promise.delay(2000);
  logger.log('info', cursor.getOperationStatus());
 }).catch(function(error) {
  throw error;
 });
});
```

Server log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status -128
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:219)
at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:227)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status -128
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.sendAndThrowMessage(TSaslTransport.java:230)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:184)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.handleSaslStartMessage(TSaslServerTransport.java:125)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:262)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport.open(TSaslServerTransport.java:41)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslServerTransport$Factory.getTransport(TSaslServerTransport.java:216)
... 4 more
```

Comment: The exception is thrown from `handleSaslStartMessage`; in other words, your JDBC client tries to negociate *how* it can authenticate to the server, but there is no agreement. There are several similar questions on S.O. (and elsewhere) about that message and it all boils down to **check the authentication method(s) expected by the server** and make sure your client uses it. Cf. http://findingthecomputer.blogspot.fr/2016/09/odbc-with-hive-on-cloudera-causing.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30905334/php-hiveserver-2-issues ...

Comment: ...and http://grokbase.com/t/hive/user/157xvy8ra8/hiveserver-thrift-ttransportexception etc.

Answer (score 2):

Samson is correct. The authentication set in my client was different from what server was expecting. Check your HiveServer2 config file `hive-site.xml`. Here is a snippet:

```xml
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.use.SSL</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
  <value>NOSASL</value>
</property>
```

It didn't have `hive.server2.authentication` property setting, so I added in there. For document reference, please look into [Cloudera's ODBC driver for Apache Hive install guide](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/hive-odbc/2-5-12/Cloudera-ODBC-Driver-for-Apache-Hive-Install-Guide-2-5-12.pdf) page 22 Configuring Authentication section